# Java Create a virtual (second) mouse

Tags: java, click, mouse, move, mousemove

Is it possible to create a second, virtual mouse.

So, there are 2 mouses at the same time.

These mouses should be moved and clicked

Comment: I found a small code https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/39493-second-mouse-cursor-alpha/ Please refer to it if it helps

Comment: how would this second mouse be controlled?

Comment: You mean a second *cursor*, presumably? It will be operating system-specific.

Comment: I have windows, it mustn't show the pointer but java should be able to click

Comment: Do you think it isn't possible with pure Java?